# Утечки памяти в OpenCV

Tags: c++, память, opencv, утечка-памяти

У меня в проекте есть такие строчки кода(с++):

```
Mat src = imread(fn);
cvtColor(src, src, CV_BGR2RGB);
```

Всё это находится в вызываемой изредка функции.
Происходит, как я могу предположить следующее:

1. по указателю `src` находится оригинальное изображение из файла.
2. `cvtColor` это изображение преобразовывает и кладёт под тем-же именем, но уже в другое место в памяти, тем самым оставляя оригинальные данные без каких-либо имён.

Вопрос: будет ли в этом месте утечка памяти, т.е. освободится ли место, где были оригинальные данные, на которые сейчас ничего не ссылается, после выхода из подпрограммы?

Comment: - Нет, утечки не будет.

- Объект `src` создан на стеке, соответственно, при выходе из функции для него будет вызван деструктор. В самом `OpenCV` даже есть [**очень похожий пример.**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html)

- Кстати, `src` — это не указатель.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с @Costantino Rupert - утечки быть не должно, я сам такое использую постоянно и работает бывает *недели* без перезагрузки, поэтому точно знаю что утечек нет. 
Я чуть менее чем уверен, что это нюансы конкретной реализации диспетчера памяти - попробуйте скомпилировать другим компилятором, или даже на другой платформе, скорее всего проблема отпадёт.

Еще попробуйте другим компилятором пересобрать OpenCV